# How can I remove the background reflection from this photo, are there any online tools?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

Is possible to remove reflection from this image?

[image]

Comment: Hi ramu, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please show us what you've tried so far? Always good to show a little effort, and it increases your chances for a good answer. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Well, it's not as easy as just removing the reflections. Materials that don't reflect its surrounding have different properties so you have to decide what kind of material you are trying to mimic here. Or are you after a glossy material that reflects an empty white room or similar?

Comment: It's a simple matter of tedious painting-in of what *should* have been there in an ideal photograph, which is why this sort of thing is usually handled in-camera (or, rather, at capture time) rather than in post-processing.  Product photography is mostly about managing reflections.

Answer (score 1):

Using Photoshop, a quick and dirty solution might be to:

1. duplicate the image onto another layer over top of the original image
2. on the new layer, select the part of the image you want to remove the reflections
3. on the new layer, keeping your selection, blur the image (gaussian?)
4. touch-up using masking and maybe go back and paint some highlights to make the material look a bit more reflective

Answer (score 0):

I would try clone stamp tool then smoothing it off. Maybe add a red gradient after.
Content aware maybe?

Comment: Can you please explain what the tool clone stamp tool is and how to use it. I guess you know that but please consider there could be people not knowing about what you are talking ...