# Photoshop: how to remove reflections from photos

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photography

I can see the reflection of a yellow jacket in my photo. Is there any way to remove the yellow colour?

Comment: To remove the yellow you could lower the red and green, but that's not going to remove the appearance of the reflection. Perhaps you could do it in a scissored area of the reflection, and blend it together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the background reflection from this photo, are there any online tools?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38798/how-can-i-remove-the-background-reflection-from-this-photo-are-there-any-online)

Comment: post the image in question and i can tell you if and how its possible

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you're expecting, but photographers will use polarizing filters to remove reflections in-camera, so they don't need to worry about too much retouching later. Check [this](https://youtu.be/iz6i548ljCE?t=32) out.

[image]

[image]